# Inserting index array to one column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert an index array into a table in MySQL? At this snippet I need to insert array items into `data`

```
$data = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];

$temtbl = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dataTable` (
           `data` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT 100        
          ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;";
$conn->query($temtbl);

$insertTotbl= "INSERT INTO `dataTable`(`data`);

$conn->query($insertTotbl);
```

### Update

```
$row =[];
$query5 = "SELECT *  FROM `dataTable`" ;
$results = $conn->query($query5);
if ($results) {
    $row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    $row = array_map('floatval', $row); 

}
$conn->close();
 echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Do you want to insert the whole array in a single field? Or do you want to insert each entry of the array as a new row in your table? (by the way, you're missing closing quotes in that snippet)

Comment: Thanks  Barranka, yes I want to insert whole array in one single field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this:

```
$data = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];

$temtbl = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dataTable` (
           `data` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT 100        
          ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;";
$conn->query($temtbl);

$insertTotbl= "INSERT INTO `dataTable`(`data`) VALUES (" . implode('),(', $data) . ")";

$conn->query($insertTotbl);
```

> update

The second part:

```
$nums = [];
$query5 = "SELECT *  FROM `dataTable`" ;
$results = $conn->query($query5);
while ($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
    $nums[] = floatval($row[0]); 
}
$conn->close();
echo json_encode(nums);
```

Comment: Thanks samlev , can you please take a look at update? when I try to get the data like updated code I am only getting NULL on the page

Comment: Updated with the second part

Comment: Thanks now I am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Shahab\index.php on line 25`

Comment: and now I am getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function float_val() in `

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. the function should be `floatval`

Answer (score 0):

You can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it before storing it:

```
<?php
$data = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];

$foo = serialize($data);

var_dump($foo); // Outputs: a:9:{i:0;i:5555;i:1;i:22;i:2;i:102858;i:3;i:12;i:4;d:0.5540000000000000479616346638067625463008880615234375;i:5;i:88888;i:6;i:99999999;i:7;i:12;i:8;d:1.5;}
```

At this point you can store `$foo` as a string in the database. When you query for the data, you can [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it get the array back:

```
$bar = unserialize($foo);

var_dump($bar); //Outputs the array.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks HPierce and how can I insert the serialized data into table?

Comment: Just a standard MySQL query: `INSERT INTO dataTable VALUES ($serializedData)`. The examples you posted looked fine. If you need me to provide a full example, I guess I can do that. Let me know.

Comment: I did but still getting NULL in return!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
foreach($data as $val)
{
$insertTotbl= "INSERT INTO `dataTable`(`data`) VALUES ('".$val."')   ";
$conn->query($insertTotbl);
}
```